# Convert Generic List to IEnumerable List to pass it to View

Tags: c#, entity-framework, model-view-controller

Convert Generic List to IEnumrable  Not Working for Me

```
public DataTable GetDataTable(string query)
{
    string connString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConString"].ToString();
    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
    conn.Open();

    // create data adapter
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    // this will query your database and return the result to your datatable
    da.Fill(dataTable);
    conn.Close();
    da.Dispose();
    return dataTable;
}
```

Generic Method to Query From Database and Pass to View

```
public IEnumerable<object> ListAll(object ObjEntity)
{     
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    List<object> objList = new List<object>();
    string TableName = ObjEntity.GetType().Name;
    string strSql = "SELECT * FROM " + TableName + ' ' + "where  delete_flag=0";
    var objmodel = GetDataTable(strSql);
    objList.Add(objmodel);
    return objList;
}
```

Action Mehod to Get All Data From List

```
public ActionResult Index(Employees employee)
{
    var listEmp = dbContext.ListAll(employee);
    return View(listEmp);
}
```

Comment: `Not Working for Me` what does it mean? What issue you are facing?

Comment: In View im facing problem from conversion into ienemerable of model type from list of datatable.

Comment: And what **exactly** would that problem be? Unless you tell us that, in detail, nobody can possibly help you. Unless they're a unicorn. Or Jon Skeet.

Comment: @DanishQureshi so you should post the code of your View if the exception is thrown there.

Comment: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Object]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Payroll_DAL.Employees]'.

Comment: You need to either change your view to take an `IEnumerable<object>`, or your `ListAll` method to return an `IEnumerable<Payroll_DAL.Employees>`. In the latter case, `Payroll_DAL.Employees` must, of course, be of type `DataTable`, since that's what you're putting in your list.

Comment: When  i am using Generic Method ListAll and calling method in controller action Index i am getting List of Collection in Generic List but on View the Error  i am Getting     The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List1[System.Object]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable1

Comment: Um, you already said that, and you've already had an answer. I can't be absolutely certain because you still haven't edited your question to include the View code, as requested earlier, but I'm pretty sure my previous comment should solve your problem